# Style class superior to all headings (h1-h6)

Tags: html, css, head

Is there a way (a class superior to all Hs, 1-6) to set a property shared among all Hs so that you don't have to put it in each one manually?  E.g. if I wanted to have an underline at the bottom of each H, I would do

`border-bottom:1px solid #999;`

Now I have to put it in each one separately whereas the property is the same.

I tried to do

`h { border-bottom:1px solid #999; }`

but it didn't work.

What I am actually doing is:

```
.main-heading
{
    border-bottom:1px solid #999;
}
```

and then

`<h3 class="main-heading">My Heading</h3>`

and that works but I would rather not use a class with an H tag since it will always be the same (simplicity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. You can just write a selector that matches all of them:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    border-bottom:1px solid #999;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { border-bottom:1px solid #999; }
```